# How to improve ugly catch block using exception instanceof

Tags: java, exception, instanceof, inherited

***Please pay attention: caller throws parentexception only!!***

Say that `aexception`, and `bexception` inherit from `parentexception`.

In method `af`, it `throws aexception`, `bexception` and `parentexception`.

```
void af() throws aexception, bexception, parentexception {}
```

The method `caller` calls `af` and `throw parentexception` only.

```
void caller() throws parentexception
```

Here we lost the information of subclasses of parentexception.

The method `rootCaller` calls the method `caller` and `rootcaller` can only `catch parentexception` thrown by `caller` and using the following exception process catch block:

```
void rootCaller() {
    try {
        caller(); 
    } catch(parentexception e) {
    if(e instanceof aexception) {
        ......
    } else   if(e instanceof bexception) {
        ......
    } else   if(e instanceof parentexception) {
        ......
    } else {
    ......
    }
}
```

This is so ugly and very easy to forget some subclass of parentexception if the subclasses are too many.

Is there anyway to improve such code?

Current answer can not give me any idea:

1, rootCaller cannnot use multi-catch to simplify the process cause caller only throw parentexception.

2, because caller only throw parentexception, there is not any other exception check if the af is changed latter to throws more than aexception and bexception, say cexception.

Comment: There's code formatting. Indent, or use front ticks,```` for inline code

Comment: Solution: **don't catch `Exception`**. Catch individual exceptions. That's why you have the `catch` clauses in the first place!

Comment: Why don't you use multiple `catch` clauses?

Comment: Is there any specific reason of checking the instance of the exception?

Comment: Do you need to handle each exception caught differently? If not, just have a single catch for parentexception.

Comment: As the code show. From function `rootCaller`, it cannot catch the subclass of parentException. because `caller` `only` throw the parentException. that's why I cannot use multiple catch clauses.

Answer (score 7):

As others have suggested in the comments, you should be using multiple catch clauses.

```
void rootCaller() {
    try {
        caller();
    } catch (AException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (ParentException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (BException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (AnotherException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**The order of the catches matters too.** The Exception will be tested against each case in turn and only trigger the first one that matches.

So for example with `AException` and `BException` extending `ParentException` in my above code the `catch (BException e)` block can never be reached as `catch (ParentException e)` is reached and executed first.

Comment: 1, after catch (ParentException e), the BException would be cared anymore. and 2, as my code show, the rootCaller cannot catch the subclass of the ParentException because it don't know them from caller function

Comment: @user1542687 Read my final paragraph. I did that on purpose to illustrate that the order does matter.